# Titanium Mobile: reference UI elements with an ID?

Tags: user-interface, mobile, callback, titanium

How do you keep track of your UI elements in Titanium? Say you have a window with a TableView that has some Switches (on/off) in it and you'd like to reference the changed switch onchange with a generic event listener. There's the property event.source, but you still don't really know what field of a form was just toggled, you just have a reference to the element. Is there a way to give the element an ID, as you would with a radiobutton in JavaScript?

Up to now, registered each form UI element in a dictionary, and saved all the values at once, looping through the dictionary and getting each object value. But now I'd like to do this onchange, and I can't find any other way to do it than create a specific callback function for each element (which I'd really rather not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just assign and id to the element... all of these other solution CAN work, but they seem to be  over kill for what you are asking for.

```
// create switch with id
var switcher0 = Ti.Ui.createSwitch({id:"switch1"});
```

then inside your event listener

```
myform.addEventListener('click', function(e){
   var obj = e.source; 
   if ( obj.id == "switch1" ) {
      // do some magic!!
   }
});
```

Comment: Yes! That is what I was looking for. Too bad they can't just put it in the docs -.-

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use a framework that helps you keep track of all your elements, which speeds up development quite a bit, as the project and app grows. I've built a framework of my own called [Adamantium.js](http://adamrenklint.com/projects/adamantium-js), which lets you use a syntax like jQuery to deal with your elements, based on **ID and type selectors**. In a coming release, it will also support for something like classes, that can be arbitrarily added or removed from an element, tracking of master/slave relationships and basic filter methods, to help you narrow your query. Most methods are chainable, so building apps with rich interaction is quick and simple.

A quick demo:

```
// Type selector, selects all switches
$(':Switch')

// Bind a callback to the change event on all switches
// This callback is also inherited by all new switch elements
$(':Switch').bind('change', function (e) {
    alert(e.type + ' fired on ' + e.source.id + ', value = ' + e.value);
});

// Select by ID and trigger an event
$('#MyCustomSwitch').trigger('change', {
    foo: 'bar'
});
```

Then there's a lot of other cool methods in the framework, that are all designed to speed up development and modeled after the familiar ways of jQuery, [more about that in the original blog post](http://adamrenklint.com/projects/adamantium-js).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'd rather not use a framework if there's a vanilla way to reference back to the element. Do you know if there is such a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I completely understand not wanting to write a listener to each one because that is very time consuming. I had the same problem that you did and solved it like so.

```
var switches = [];
function createSwitch(i) {
    switches[i] = Ti.UI.createSwitch();
    switches[i].addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        Ti.API.info('switch '+i+' = '+e.value);
    });
    return switches[i];
}

for(i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {
    row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow();
    row.add(createSwitch(i));   
}
```

However keep in mind that this solution may not fit your needs as it did mine. For me it was good because each time I created a switch it added a listener to it dynamically then I could simply get the `e.source.parent` of the switch to interact with whatever I needed.

Answer (score 1):

module Id just for the hold it's ID. When we have use id the call any another space just use . and use easily.
Try This

```
var but1 = Ti.Ui.createButton({title : 'Button', id:"1"});

window.addEventListener('click', function(e){
   var obj = e.source; 
   if ( obj.id == "1" ) {
      // do some magic!!
   }
});
window.add(but1);
```

I, think this is supported for you.

Answer (score 0):

how do you create your tableview and your switcher? usually i would define a eventListener function while creating the switcher.

```
// first switch
var switcher0 = Ti.Ui.createSwitch();
switch0.addEventListener('change',function(e){});
myTableViewRow.add(switch0);
myTableView.add(myTableViewRow);

// second switch
var switch1 = ..
```

so no generic event listener is needed.

Comment: I create the switches generically from data objects, so creating a custom change listener for each switch is, like I said, not really the way I want to go.